# YII main.php access database table values

Tags: php, yii

how to access the database table values in main.php

```
return array(
                'onBeginRequest'=>array('dbVar'),
);
```

it return values ,

in dbVar.php i have the functions like this,

```
class dbVar{
        public static function getList(){
            $dependency = new CDbCacheDependency('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1');
            $data = Yii::app()->db->cache(Yii::app()->params['cacheInterval'], $dependency)->createCommand('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=1')->queryRow();
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($data);
            exit;       
        }
    }
```

how to access the return values in the main.php,